# How to install ecryptfs-utils on RHEL8.1

Tags: rhel, package-management

I have added the EPFL repository on RHEL8.1 but am unable to find `ecryptfs-utils` package:

```
# yum search ecryptfs-utils
#
```

**What repository should I add in order to install ecryptfs on RHEL8?**

Answer (score 1):

I’m not aware of a repository providing `ecryptfs-utils` for RHEL 8. The package was removed in RHEL 7, and [the upgrade path is to switch to LUKS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-package_replacements) (re-encrypting the data).

However it is [still available in Fedora](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/ecryptfs-utils/branches?branchname=master), and in EPEL 7, so you could request a build for EPEL 8; see [the `ecryptfs-utils` EPEL 7 request](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1178673) for a template.